# Atom Proxy Configuration Not Working: error self signed certificate in certificate chain

Tags: atom-editor

I've been trying all the examples I found online, but couldn't get it to work. When I try to install or search for a package, I get "self signed certificate in certificate chain". Here's what I've tried:

**Command line attempts:**

```
apm config set strict-ssl false
apm config set http-proxy http://katie:fakepassword@fakeproxy.company.com:8080
apm config set https-proxy http://katie:fakepassword@fakeproxy.company.com:8080
# I then start atom using this terminal window like this:
atom
```

**Contents of `~/.atom/.apmrc`:**

```
http-proxy=http://katie:fakepassword@fakeproxy.company.com:8080
https-proxy=http://katie:fakepassword@fakeproxy.company.com:8080
strict-ssl=false
```

**Adding configuration to `~/.bashrc`:**

```
#I also added these configuration lines to my ~/.bashrc to ensure my configuration is kept for every new terminal:
username="katie"
password="fakepassword"
proxy="fakeproxy.company.com:8080"
echo "http-proxy=http://$username:$password@$proxy" > ~/.atom/.apmrc
echo "https-proxy=http://$username:$password@$proxy" >> ~/.atom/.apmrc
echo "strict-ssl=false" >> ~/.atom/.apmrc
apm config set strict-ssl false
apm config set http-proxy http://$username:$password@$proxy
apm config set https-proxy http://$username:$password@$proxy
```

**Output of `apm config list`**

```
`-->$ apm config list
; cli configs
globalconfig = "/home/katie/.atom/.apm/.apmrc"
user-agent = "npm/3.10.10 node/v6.9.5 linux x64"
userconfig = "/home/katie/.atom/.apmrc"

; environment configs
node-gyp = "/usr/share/atom/resources/app/apm/bin/../node_modules/.bin/node-gyp"
python = "/usr/share/atom/resources/app/apm/bin/python-interceptor.sh"

; userconfig /home/katie/.atom/.apmrc
http-proxy = "http://katie:fakepassword@fakeproxy.company.com:8080"
https-proxy = "http://katie:fakepassword@fakeproxy.company.com:8080/"
strict-ssl = false

; globalconfig /home/katie/.atom/.apm/.apmrc
cache = "/home/katie/.atom/.apm"
progress = false

; node bin location = /usr/share/atom/resources/app/apm/bin/node
; cwd = /home/katie/DRIVES/H
; HOME = /home/katie/.atom/.node-gyp
; "npm config ls -l" to show all defaults.
```

I've tried all of the above and still when I open atom, I get the following error when trying to install or search for any packages:

[image: self signed certificate in certificate chain]

However, **I am able to install packages through the command line** interface using `apm install file-icons`, but the *GUI* does not allow me to install.

**How do I configure atom so that it ignores self signed certificates in the GUI?**

Comment: I am experiencing the same behaviour. Have you been able to get the GUI working?

Comment: @BustedSanta Unfortunately I gave up :( sorry about that

Comment: thanks. I will post findings if I get to the bottom of the issue.

Comment: it seems to be a known issue... this is a related thread... unfortunately, it's been closed, so it appears to be a dead end - https://github.com/atom/settings-view/issues/1063

Comment: Yeah the github is a dead end. every issue on it points back to the same closed for inactivity issue.